# How to reset Jenkins security settings from the command line?

Tags: linux, security, jenkins, command-line

Is there a way to reset all (or just disable the security settings) from the command line without a user/password as I have managed to completely lock myself out of `Jenkins`?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

The simplest solution is to completely disable security - change `true` to `false` in `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` file.

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

A one-liner to achieve the same:

```
sed -i 's/<useSecurity>true<\/useSecurity>/<useSecurity>false<\/useSecurity>/g' /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

Then just restart Jenkins:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

And then go to admin panel and set everything once again.

If you in case are running your Jenkins inside a Kubernetes pod and can not run `service` command, then you can just restart Jenkins by deleting the pod:

```
kubectl delete pod <jenkins-pod-name>
```

Once the command was issued, Kubernetes will terminate the old pod and start a new one.

Comment: I needed to restart Jenkins for change to apply.

Comment: `sudo service jenkins restart`

Comment: To those who can't find it their config.xml use `find / -name "config.xml" ` in your terminal.

Comment: After Changing user Security  tag to false for restart jenking from command prompt --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869311/start-stop-and-restart-jenkins-service-on-windows

Comment: This leaves your Jenkins installation unsecured while you recreate your configuration. I prefer aruseni's answer below.

Comment: Also file could be located under ~/.jenkins/ folder

Comment: On mac when installed with brew the config file is at: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/config.xml

Comment: I just lost the password after setting everything up due to my bad use of lastpass and I just did `sudo service jenkins stop` then `sudo yum remove jenkins` and `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/` and then I installed jenkins again in my AMI.

Comment: I am not able to change the config.xml as it is readonly. How do i do that

Comment: sed -i 's/<useSecurity>true<\/useSecurity>/<useSecurity>false<\/useSecurity>/g' config.xml

Comment: The flag reverts to true automatically after restart

Comment: consider volumes when following this steps in case it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: I changed the config.xml file as suggested, putting <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>. I then restarted using the command sudo service jenkins restart. After restarting, the config.xml file changed by itself - I saw the date was updated. When I reopened the file, it was back to <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> @nowaker

Comment: For Jenkins in Docker, this file is in the container at `/var/jenkins_home/config.xml`. Viewed from the host (wirh default settings) at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/jenkins_home/_data/config.xml`

Answer (score 206):

One other way would be to manually edit the configuration file for your user (e.g. /var/lib/jenkins/users/username/config.xml) and update the contents of **passwordHash**:

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$razd3L1aXndFfBNHO95aj.IVrFydsxkcQCcLmujmFQzll3hcUrY7S</passwordHash>
```

Once you have done this, just restart Jenkins and log in using this password:

```
test
```

Comment: what if this entry is not there - where to actually put it?

Comment: the `<passwordHash>` xml tag is a child of `<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>`.

Look at the default admin user for an idea of the total XML structure.

Comment: This is a good solution that keeps the installation secure. Out of curiosity, how does one generate that password hash?

Comment: Modifying the contents of file present in C:\Users\<USER>\.jenkins\users\admin helped resolve the issue

Comment: didt work in win7 for me, however able to disable security using the accepted answer.

Comment: what is the password algo used, so that I can decrypt to my password. I totaly understand and agree with this log of using std password. But to be known

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer. To answer a previous question @kontextify , I believe that the user who shared the answer has encrypted the password "test" himself and shared the hash with us. Ideally, there should be no way to get the password from a hash :D.

Comment: This method still works on Tomcat 9.  Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Use this online tool to generate the Hash for any password: https://www.javainuse.com/onlineBcrypt

Comment: Not that apart from Jenkins (app / container) restart, you may also need to refresh the login page too.

Answer (score 46):

The `<passwordHash>` element in `users/<username>/config.xml` will accept data of the format

```
salt:sha256("password{salt}")
```

So, if your salt is `bar` and your password is `foo` then you can produce the SHA256 like this:

```
echo -n 'foo{bar}' | sha256sum
```

You should get `7f128793bc057556756f4195fb72cdc5bd8c5a74dee655a6bfb59b4a4c4f4349` as the result. Take the hash and put it with the salt into `<passwordHash>`:

```
<passwordHash>bar:7f128793bc057556756f4195fb72cdc5bd8c5a74dee655a6bfb59b4a4c4f4349</passwordHash>
```

Restart Jenkins, then try logging in with password `foo`. Then reset your password to something else. (Jenkins uses bcrypt by default, and one round of SHA256 is not a secure way to store passwords. You'll get a bcrypt hash stored when you reset your password.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. an example starts with a salt of #jbscrypt and then defines encrypt fields $2a$10$.  What do these mean?

Comment: My answer worked for me. The additional fields you're seeing are for a different hash format. The library Jenkins uses for handling hashed passwords supports more than one format. The jbcrypt format you're referring to is more secure than sha256 with a salt, but the sha256+salt format can be easily produced from the command line---recall that the point of the exercise is to get back into Jenkins, and then change the password from Jenkins' web interface.

Comment: This also did not work for me. I'll try to find more info on bcrypt

Comment: it worked for me. I used the following commands:
```
PASSWORD_DIGEST="$(echo -n "${ADMIN_PASSWORD}{${SALT}}" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')"
echo "password digest: $PASSWORD_DIGEST"

sed -i -e "s#<passwordHash>.*</passwordHash>#<passwordHash>${SALT}:${PASSWORD_DIGEST}</passwordHash>#" "/usr/share/jenkins/ref/users/admin/config.xml"
sed -i -e "s#<apiToken>.*</apiToken>#<apiToken>${API_TOKEN}</apiToken>#" "/usr/share/jenkins/ref/users/admin/config.xml"
```

Comment: Thanks a mil. Used exact same values and worked like a charm. Got myself back in and reset pass.

Comment: Pay attention to the bar: in the <passwordHash>. That's your salt. Delete everything in the element, add "bar:", then your hash result.

Answer (score 43):

I found the file in question located in /var/lib/jenkins called config.xml, modifying that fixed the issue.

Comment: I am using El-Capitan and config.xml couldn't be found in the location

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Did you install it with bitnami stack?

The config file would be in `/Applications/jenkins-2.19.3-0/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/users/admin/config.xml`

Comment: @ryanzec, Nowakers answer uses the same file but it's better explained, you should  consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: where we will find the file in hight sierra

Answer (score 26):

In El-Capitan *config.xml* can not be found at

> /var/lib/jenkins/

Its available in

> ~/.jenkins

then after that as other mentioned open the *config.xml* file and make the following changes

- In this replace `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` with `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`
- Remove `<authorizationStrategy>` and `<securityRealm>`
- Save it and restart the jenkins(*sudo service jenkins restart*)

Comment: I am not able to edit the config.xml file actually. When i try to save it using vim it throws that it is a read only file and operation to make it write access is not permitted.

Answer (score 19):

The answer on modifying was correct. Yet, I think it should be mentioned that `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` looks something like this if you have activated "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy". Deleting `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml` and restarting jenkins also does the trick. I also deleted the users in `/var/lib/jenkins/users` to start from scratch.

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Configure:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Connect:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Create:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Delete:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Computer.Disconnect:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <!-- if this is missing for your user and it is the only one, bad luck -->
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Hudson.RunScripts:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Build:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Cancel:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Create:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Delete:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Discover:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.Item.Workspace:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Configure:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Create:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Delete:jenkins-admin</permission>
    <permission>hudson.model.View.Read:jenkins-admin</permission>
  </authorizationStrategy>
```

Answer (score 17):

We can reset the password while leaving security on.

The config.xml file in /var/lib/Jenkins/users/admin/ acts sort of like the /etc/shadow file Linux or UNIX-like systems or the SAM file in Windows, in the sense that it stores the hash of the account's password.

If you need to reset the password without logging in, you can edit this file and replace the old hash with a new one generated from bcrypt:

```
$ pip install bcrypt
$ python
>>> import bcrypt
>>> bcrypt.hashpw("yourpassword", bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10, prefix=b"2a"))
'YOUR_HASH'
```

This will output your hash, with prefix 2a, the correct prefix for Jenkins hashes.

Now, edit the config.xml file:

```
...
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:REPLACE_THIS</passwordHash>
...
```

Once you insert the new hash, reset Jenkins:

(if you are on a system with systemd):

```
sudo systemctl restart Jenkins
```

You can now log in, and you didn't leave your system open for a second.

Comment: it worked, but just to highlight that the method `hashpw` needs a `bytes` parameter instead of `str`, greetings :)

Answer (score 15):

To disable Jenkins security in simple steps in Linux, run these commands:

```
sudo ex +g/useSecurity/d +g/authorizationStrategy/d -scwq /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
```

It will remove `useSecurity` and `authorizationStrategy` lines from your `config.xml` root config file and restart your Jenkins.

See also: [Disable security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) at Jenkins website

---

After gaining the access to Jenkins, you can re-enable security in your *Configure Global Security* page by choosing the [Access Control/Security Realm](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins). After than don't forget to [create the admin user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10825614/55075).

Comment: It worked for me, however, it's skipping the authorization now.

Comment: @hemanto You need to enable security to re-enable authorization. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 14):

To reset it **without disabling security** if you're using matrix permissions (probably easily adaptable to other login methods):

1. In `config.xml`, set **`disableSignup`** to `false`.
2. **Restart** Jenkins.
3. Go to the Jenkins web page and **sign up with a new user**.
4. In `config.xml`, duplicate one of the `<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:username</permission>` lines and replace *`username`* with the new user.
5. If it's a private server, set **`disableSignup`** back to `true` in `config.xml`.
6. **Restart** Jenkins.
7. Go to the Jenkins web page and **log in as the new user**.
8. **Reset the password** of the original user.
9. **Log in** as the original user.

Optional cleanup:

1. Delete the new user.
2. Delete the temporary `<permission>` line in `config.xml`.

No securities were harmed during this answer.

Comment: Add to cleanup set disableSignup back to true, and restart jenkins

Comment: Adding the new user (kapil) inside the assignedSIDs tag as follows: ```<assignedSIDs><sid>kapil</sid></assignedSIDs>``` inside the config.xml worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

On the offchance you accidentally lock yourself out of Jenkins due to a permission mistake, and you dont have server-side access to switch to the jenkins user or root... You can make a job in Jenkins and add this to the Shell Script:

```
sed -i 's/<useSecurity>true/<useSecurity>false/' ~/config.xml
```

Then click Build Now and restart Jenkins (or the server if you need to!)

Comment: How do you create a job in Jenkins in case you have yourself locked out of it?

Comment: In this case, I had a normal Chrome window logged in and I altered the security settings and tested in an Incognito Window before logging out of the main window. The test did not let me log in, but my sessions persisted in the main window so I could repair the damage.

Comment: I believe part of the security settings I'd changed also meant that my auth session no longer had permission to alter Jenkins security configurations.

Comment: Run into this problem after activating `ProjectMatrixAuthorization`. When I do the change and restart Jenkins I see a Java-exception in the Jenkins-UI. To fix this, I removed also the line with `authorizationStrategy` and it was okay again. Jenkins readded it on the next start as an empty tag.

Answer (score 5):

```
\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

Copy the password from the initialAdminPassword file and paste it into the Jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

1 first check location if you install war or Linux or windows based on that

for example if war under Linux and for admin user

> /home/"User_NAME"/.jenkins/users/admin/config.xml

go  to this tag after #jbcrypt:

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$3DzCGLQr2oYXtcot4o0rB.wYi5kth6e45tcPpRFsuYqzLZfn1pcWK</passwordHash>
```

change this password using use any website for bcrypt hash generator

```
https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator
```

make sure it start with **$2a** cause this one jenkens uses

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove the by default security for jenkins in Windows OS,

You can traverse through the file Config.xml created inside /users/{UserName}/.jenkins.

Inside this file you can change the code from

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

To,

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Answer (score 3):

step-1 : go to the directory cd .jenkins/secrets then you will get a 'initialAdminPassword'.

step-2 : nano initialAdminPassword

you will get a password

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

changing the `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>` will not be enough, you should remove `<authorizationStrategy>` and `<securityRealm>` elements too and restart your jenkins server by doing `sudo service jenkins restart` .

remember this, set `<usesecurity>` to `false` only may cause a problem for you, since these instructions are mentioned in thier official documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security).

Answer (score 2):

> Jenkins over KUBENETES and Docker

In case of **Jenkins** over a container managed by a **Kubernetes POD** is a bit more complex since: `kubectl exec PODID --namespace=jenkins  -it -- /bin/bash` will you allow to access directly to the container running Jenkins, but **you will not have root access**, `sudo`, `vi` and many commands are not available and therefore a workaround is needed.

Use `kubectl describe pod [...]` to find the node running your Pod and the container ID `(docker://...)`

- `SSH` into the node
- run `docker exec -ti -u root -- /bin/bash` to access the container with Root privileges
- `apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install vim`

**The second difference** is that the Jenkins configuration file are placed in a different path that corresponds to the mounting point of the persistent volume, i.e. `/var/jenkins_home`, this location might change in the future, check it running `df`.

Then disable security - change true to false in `/var/jenkins_home/jenkins/config.xml` file.

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Now it is enough to restart the Jenkins, action that will cause the container and the Pod to die, it will created again in some seconds with the configuration updated (and all the chance like vi, update erased) thanks to the persistent volume.

The whole solution has been tested on Google Kubernetes Engine.
**UPDATE**
Notice that you can as well run `ps -aux` the password in plain text is shown even without root access.

```
jenkins@jenkins-87c47bbb8-g87nw:/$ps -aux
[...]
jenkins [..] -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --argumentsRealm.passwd.jenkins=password --argumentsRealm.roles.jenkins=admin
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Easy way out of this is to use the admin psw to login with your admin user:

- Change to root user: `sudo su -`
- Copy the password: `xclip -sel clip < /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
- Login with admin and press `ctrl + v` on password input box.

## Install xclip if you don't have it:

- `$ sudo apt-get install xclip`

Comment: Using the default password worked for me. To keep it simple, you could just do 'cat secrets/initialAdminPassword' rather than installing xclip for a one-off.

Comment: Sometimes this password is not present. I am not sure how you can bypass this config but for me, it is not present and I had to edit config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Using bcrypt you can solve this issue. Extending the @Reem answer for someone who is trying to automate the process using bash and python.

```
#!/bin/bash

pip install bcrypt
yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install xmlstarlet

cat > /tmp/jenkinsHash.py <<EOF
import bcrypt
import sys

if not sys.argv[1]:
  sys.exit(10)

plaintext_pwd=sys.argv[1]
encrypted_pwd=bcrypt.hashpw(sys.argv[1], bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10, prefix=b"2a"))
isCorrect=bcrypt.checkpw(plaintext_pwd, encrypted_pwd)

if not isCorrect:
   sys.exit(20);

print "{}".format(encrypted_pwd)
EOF

chmod +x /tmp/jenkinsHash.py
cd /var/lib/jenkins/users/admin*
pwd
while (( 1 )); do
    echo "Waiting for Jenkins to generate admin user's config file ..."

    if [[ -f "./config.xml" ]]; then
        break
    fi

    sleep 10
done

echo "Admin config file created"

admin_password=$(python /tmp/jenkinsHash.py password 2>&1)

# Repalcing the new passowrd
xmlstarlet -q ed --inplace -u "/user/properties/hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details/passwordHash" -v '#jbcrypt:'"$admin_password" config.xml

# Restart
systemctl restart jenkins
sleep 10
```

I have kept password hardcoded here but it can be a user input depending upon the requirement. Also make sure to add that `sleep` otherwise any other command revolving around Jenkins will fail.

Answer (score 1):

To very simply disable both security and the startup wizard, use the JAVA property:

```
-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

The nice thing about this is that you can use it in a Docker image such that your container will always start up immediately with no login screen:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
```

Note that, as mentioned by others, the Jenkins config.xml is in `/var/jenkins_home` in the image, but using `sed` to modify it from the Dockerfile fails, because (presumably) the config.xml doesn't exist until the server starts.

Answer (score 1):

I will add some improvements based on the solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255443/5322871

On my scenario it was deployed with Swarm cluster with nfs volume, in order to perform the password reset I did the following:

- Attach to the pod:

```bash
$ docker exec -it <pod-name> bash
```

- Generate the hash password with python (do not forget to specify the letter **`b`** outside of your quoted password, the method `hashpw` requires a parameter in bytes):

```bash
$ pip install bcrypt
$ python
>>> import bcrypt
>>> bcrypt.hashpw(b"yourpassword", bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=10, prefix=b"2a"))
'YOUR_HASH'
```

- Once inside the container find all the `config.xml` files:

```bash
$ find /var/ -type f -iname "config.xml"
```

- Once identified, modify value of the field ( on my case the config.xml was in another location):

```bash
$ vim /var/jenkins_home/users/admin_9482805162890262115/config.xml
```

```xml
...
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:YOUR_HASH</passwordHash>
...
```

- Restart the service:

```bash
docker service scale <service-name>=0
docker service scale <service-name>=1
```

Hope this can be helpful for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and following reply from ArtB,

I found that my user didn't have the proper configurations. so what I did:

**Note: manually modifying such XML files is risky. Do it at your own risk. Since I was already locked out, I didn't have much to lose. AFAIK Worst case I would have deleted the ~/.jenkins/config.xml file as prev post mentioned.**

**> 1. ssh to the jenkins machine

> 1. cd ~/.jenkins   (I guess that some installations put it under /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml, but not in my case )
> 2. vi config.xml, and under authorizationStrategy xml tag, add the below section (just used my username instead of "put-your-username")
> 3. restart jenkins. in my case as root service tomcat7 stop; ; service tomcat7 start
> 4. Try to login again. (worked for me)**

under

add:

```
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Build:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Configure:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Connect:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Create:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Delete:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Computer.Disconnect:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.ConfigureUpdateCenter:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.Read:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.RunScripts:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Hudson.UploadPlugins:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Build:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Cancel:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Configure:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Create:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Delete:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Discover:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Read:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Workspace:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Run.Delete:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.Run.Update:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.View.Configure:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.View.Create:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.View.Delete:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.model.View.Read:put-your-username</permission>
<permission>hudson.scm.SCM.Tag:put-your-username</permission>
```

Now, you can go to different directions. For example I had github oauth integration, so I could have tried to replace the authorizationStrategy with something like below:

**Note:, It worked in my case because I had a specific github oauth plugin that was already configured. So it is more risky than the previous solution.**

```
  <authorizationStrategy class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy" plugin="github-oauth@0.14">
    <rootACL>
      <organizationNameList class="linked-list">
        <string></string>
      </organizationNameList>
      <adminUserNameList class="linked-list">
        <string>put-your-username</string>
        <string>username2</string>
        <string>username3</string>
        <string>username_4_etc_put_username_that_will_become_administrator</string>
      </adminUserNameList>
      <authenticatedUserReadPermission>true</authenticatedUserReadPermission>
      <allowGithubWebHookPermission>false</allowGithubWebHookPermission>
      <allowCcTrayPermission>false</allowCcTrayPermission>
      <allowAnonymousReadPermission>false</allowAnonymousReadPermission>
    </rootACL>
  </authorizationStrategy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml and change de security configuration with this:

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy$Unsecured"/>
```

After that restart Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times you wont be having permissions to edit the config.xml file.

The simplest thing would be to take a back of `config.xml` and delete using sudo command.

Restart the jenkins using the command `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart`

This will disable all the security in the Jenkins and the login option would disappear

Comment: If you can delete config.xml with sudo, you can edit it with sudo too. e.g. sudo vi ...

Answer (score 0):

For one who is using macOS, the new version just can be installed by homebrew. so for resting, this command line must be using:

```
brew services restart jenkins-lts
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory where the file is located config.xml in windows

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).