# How can I add a username and password to Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

When I go to `mydomain.example:8080` there is no authorization mechanism by default. I have had look at the configuration area but cannot find anywhere to add a basic username and password

Comment: I believe this page gives the answer: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

Comment: Related: [Creating user in Jenkins via API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17716242/55075).

Comment: You can go to http://JENKINURL/configureSecurity and select Security Realm/Jenkins’ own user database. It will ask you to go back to login page where you can find create new user option

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Go to *Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security* and select the *Enable Security* checkbox.

For the basic username/password authentication, I would recommend selecting *Jenkins Own User Database* for the security realm and then selecting *Logged in Users can do anything* or a matrix based strategy (in case when you have multiple users with different permissions) for the *Authorization*.

Comment: In 1.507 this is instead Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security.

Comment: The instructions are helpful, but don't actually tell how to *add a user* to Jenkins.

Comment: found topic. wasn't helpful. found other topic & found solution:
top-right 'register' creates(adds) user.

Comment: Good, but now I can block "sing up" for all others users?
For example, I want have only one admin user and dissable "sing up" for all others

Comment: @JavaDude There's an option to enable/disable user sign up under Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Jenkins’ own user database

Comment: [This was the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056851/add-users-to-jenkins-with-allow-users-to-sign-up-disabled/12365640#12365640) I was seeking. Navigate to "Manage Jenkins" → "Manage Users" → "Create User"

Comment: If you don't see "Manage Users" link, it's because you have to set up the security at 'Configure Global Security'

Comment: After enabling security for "Jenkins Own User Database", the next screen prompts you to enter a username/password to create a new user.

Comment: how can i block non logged in users from even the main page? not only from administrative options.. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have *Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Enable Security* and *Jenkins Own User Database* checked you would go to:

- *Manage Jenkins > Manage Users > Create User*

Answer (score 1):

- Try deleting the .jenkins folder from your system which is located ate the below path.
  `C:\Users\"Your PC Name"\.jenkins`
- Now download a fresh and a stable version of .war file from official website of jenkins. For eg. 2.1 and follow the steps to install.
- You will be able to do via this method

Answer (score 0):

You need to *Enable security* and set the security realm on the *Configure Global Security* page (see: [Standard Security Setup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)) and choose the appropriate Authorization method (*Security Realm*).

[image: Jenkins Security Realm, Hudson's own user database]

Depending on your selection, create the user using appropriate method.  Recommended method is to select *Jenkins’ own user database* and tick *Allow users to sign up*, hit Save button, then you should be able to create user from the Jenkins interface. Otherwise if you've chosen external database, you need to create the user there (e.g. if it's Unix database, use credentials of existing Linux/Unix users or create a standard user using shell interface).

See also: [Creating user in Jenkins via API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17716242/55075)

Answer (score 0):

If installed as an admin, use:

```
uname - admin
pw - the passkey that was generated during installation
```