# Not able to "Unlock the Jenkins". Even I'm entering the right secret key. The page is reloading

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

After deploying the jenkins.war in Apache Tomcat server. the Jenkins is started running.

Once I hit on the browser http://localhost:8080/jenkins. Its asking me to enter the password. I'm entering the right password, but this page is refreshing back to the same page. It's blinking and coming back to same page.

Here is the Apache Tomcat Log message.

---

---

---

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

c3ca6360fa014c5d9143286484696217

This may also be found at: C:\Users\arvind.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

---

---

---

Sep 11, 2016 12:59:59 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Sep 11, 2016 1:00:00 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you can also skip that initial admin password page by creating a dummy file called `jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion` in Jenkins home.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37172067/6606196) for more information.

Once you place that file in the jenkins home and restart the service, you will be prompted to login using a username/password.  Unless you are reinstalling Jenkins, you will probably not have one.  To get around this screen, you can temporarily disable Jenkins security and create a user through "Manage Jenkins".  See [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) for information for disabling security.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12365640/6606196) for creating new users.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the old jenkins.war file from webapps and .jenkins folder too. Copied the new file into webapps folder, restarted the server and redeployed the jenkins.war file. Now its taking initial password. working fine.