# How to create jenkins credentials via the REST API?

Tags: jenkins

I need to create a jenkins credential ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin ) via a script. How can I do that using either the REST API or the cli ?

Note that I'm able to list the credentials using /credential-store/domain/*/api/json and /credential-store/domain/*/credential/8bd82461-e239-4db1-90bc-831ca3412e70/api/json etc.

Comment: not sure with the possibility of CLI or Rest. But it can be achieved in python or groovy using jenkins api

Comment: When I create secret with white spaces using the API, get `Caused: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to parse JSON:{"": "7", "credentials"...`
Any idea?

Answer (score 37):

This issue took me a while to figure, a lot of digging around, so I decided to let the solution here, if someone else needs it.

```
curl -X POST 'http://user:token@jenkins_server:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "identification",
    "username": "manu",
    "password": "bar",
    "description": "linda",
    "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}'
```

Comment: that looks very interesting ! Would you mind sharing the details of the reasoning that lead you to this conclusion ?

Comment: this looks useful..is there something to delete credentials as well?

Comment: Just addind how the json looks like with secret text, as we quite often use tokens these days:
    {
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "myid",
    "secret": "mysecret",
    "description": "mydescription",
    "$class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl"
  }
}

Comment: What does "":"0" mean?

Comment: What should we use for the "id"?

Comment: @csviri  I am also looking a way to update the existing secret text using REST API. If I want to update the existing value, how it can be done? have you done that ?

Comment: @Ros5292 did you try it just posting it again? That should do the job if I remember it correctly.

Comment: Yes I tried re posting it with updated value but I could see old value and not the updated value.

Comment: @Ros5292 did you figure out a way to update the existing credential?

Answer (score 17):

with latest jenkins you need a CRUMB to authenticate for this operation (ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314286)

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://user:token@jenkins_server:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST 'http://user:token@jenkins_server:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "identification",
    "username": "manu",
    "password": "bar",
    "description": "linda",
    "$class": "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl"
  }
}'
```

Otherwise you get

```
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
```

Comment: What should we use for the "id"?

Comment: No you don't need a crumb if you use an access token to authenticate to jenkins

Comment: @zhangjinzhou ``id`` is the name of the credential in Jenkins

Answer (score 6):

if you need to create credentials but with pem file path you can use this:

> prerequisites: ssh-credentials plugin

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://{{jenkins_admin_username}}:{{jenkins_admin_password}}@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST 'http://{{jenkins_admin_username}}:{{jenkins_admin_password}}@localhost:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "'{{ii.ssh_user}}'",
    "username": "'{{ii.ssh_user}}'",
    "password": "",
    "privateKeySource": {
      "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$FileOnMasterPrivateKeySource",
      "privateKeyFile": "'{{jenkins_home}}/{{ii.key_name}}.pem'",
    },
    "description": "'{{ii.ssh_user}}'",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
  }
}'
```

this command used in ansible but you can replace the {{variables}} with your own variables

if you need to add all the pem file content you need to change the lines to:

```
....      
"stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
      "privateKey": "{{private_key_content}}",
    },
    "description": "{{user}}",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Just adding my 2 cents here: if you want to create the credentials for a specific folder, then use the following:

```
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST 'http://user:token@jenkins_server:8080/job/MY_FOLDER_NAME/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/createCredentials' \
...
```

So, you need to use /job/My_Folder at the beginning of the query part and replace the /store/system with /store/folder

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific API call for this, but you can do it via cli commands to the jenkins jar.

```
echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("username", "password")' | java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost/ groovy =
```

For granting them permissions you can create a task in Jenkins which is running every N minutes and executing a groovy script as described here:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Grant+Cancel+Permission+for+user+and+group+that+have+Build+permission

Comment: Here is what I get  (probably because this is version sensitive ? I'm using jenkins 1.596.1) : `echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("username", "password")' | java -jar ~/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:11080/ groovy =
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.security.SecurityRealm$None.createAccount() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [username, password]`

Comment: It looks like this is is for account creation though, not for credentials, right ?

Comment: How do you create an admin user with a call like this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a groovy script that also sets user permission using Matrix-based security. The script was posted at [Creating user in Jenkins via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716242/creating-user-in-jenkins-via-api/33488587#33488587)

Comment: unrealted to original question

Answer (score 1):

[Unable to point to ssh keys in ~/.ssh on Jenkins host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119412/unable-to-point-to-ssh-keys-in-ssh-on-jenkins-host)

Means this no longer works,

```
"privateKeySource": {
  "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$FileOnMasterPrivateKeySource",
  "privateKeyFile": "'{{jenkins_home}}/{{ii.key_name}}.pem'",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is the official documentation for managing the Jenkins Credentials via REST API

https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc#creating-a-credentials

Example of adding a `deploy-key` credential using the username `wecoyote` and the password `secret123` in the `testing` domain of the `/example-folder` folder.

```bash
$ cat > credential.xml <<EOF
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
  <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
  <id>deploy-key</id>
  <description>Test User</description>
  <usernameSecret>false</usernameSecret>
  <username>wecoyote</username>
  <password>secret123</password>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl>
EOF

$ curl -X POST -u <username>:<password_or_token> -H content-type:application/xml -d @credential.xml \
https://jenkins.example.com/job/example-folder/credentials/store/folder/\
domain/testing/createCredentials
```

> The expected responses are:
>
> **HTTP/200 Success**, the credentials has been created.
>
> **HTTP/409 Failure**, a credential with that id already exists.
>
> **HTTP/50x** Could not parse the supplied domain XML body.