# Upload secret file credentials to Jenkins with REST / CLI

Tags: rest, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

How can I create a Jenkins Credential via REST API or Jenkins CLI? The credential should be of type "secret file", instead of a username / password combination.

The question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616660/how-to-create-jenkins-credentials-via-the-rest-api), but not the same or a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
curl -X POST \
 https://jenkins.local/job/TEAM-FOLDER/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/createCredentials \
 -F secret=@/Users/maksym/secret \
 -F 'json={"": "4", "credentials": {"file": "secret", "id": "test", 
"description": "HELLO-curl", "stapler-class": 
"org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl", 
"$class": 
"org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl"}}'
```

just finished with it today https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/upload-jenkins-secret-file-credential-via-api-maksym-lushpenko/?trackingId=RDcgSk0KyvW5RxrBD2t1RA%3D%3D

Comment: Did you find a way to update an existing creds file? Repeating this request with a different file gets ignored.

Comment: I had to do a check if secret is present via API, then delete it and upload new one, did it via Ansible, had the same problem

Comment: I'm getting  `HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request`

Comment: You can check a number of options here about that error https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2067

Answer (score 8):

To create Jenkins credentials via the CLI you can use the `create-credentials-by-xml` command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <JENKINS_URL> create-credentials-by-xml  system::system::jenkins _ < credential-name.xml
```

The best way to know the syntax of this is to create a credential manually, and then dump it:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <JENKINS_URL> get-credentials-as-xml system::system::jenkins _ credential-name > credential-name.xml
```

Then you can use this XML example as a template, it should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update an existing secret file, the simplest way I found was to delete and re-create.

A delete request, to extend @lumaks answer (i.e. with the same hostname, folder name and credentials id), looks like:

```
curl -v -X POST \
-u "user:password" \
https://jenkins.local/job/TEAM-FOLDER/credentials/store/folder/domain/_/credential/test/doDelete
```

This will return either HTTP status code `302 Found` or `404 Not Found` for existing and non-existing creds file respectively.

Comment: Is there some full Credentials Plugin API reference? It is kind of struggle to search a bits of information about it all over the internet.