# Unable to point to ssh keys in ~/.ssh on Jenkins host

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-agent

I've installed SSH Agent Plugin to pull Git repository using SSH authentication. I'd like to use SSH keys located in system file (from the Jenkins master `~/.ssh` option). It's screenshot taken from official plugin's page:

[image: Screen from official plugin's page]

Unfortunately I don't see this option. I can select only "Enter directly". Please check out my screenshot.

[image: my screenshot]

Did I configure something wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a reletively recent change, explained in security advisory 440 : https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2018-06-25/

> SECURITY-440 / CVE-2018-1000601
>   SSH Credentials Plugin allowed the creation of SSH credentials with keys "From a file on Jenkins master". Credentials Binding Plugin 1.13 and newer allows binding SSH credentials to environment variables. In combination, these two features allow users with the permission to configure a job to read arbitrary files on the Jenkins master by creating an SSH credential referencing an arbitrary file on the Jenkins master, and binding it to an environment variable in a job.
>
> SSH Credentials Plugin **no longer supports SSH credentials from files on the Jenkins master file system**, neither user-specified file paths nor ~/.ssh. Existing SSH credentials of these kinds are migrated to "directly entered" SSH credentials.

Answer (score 0):

That option (first screen) is from the `Jenkins | Manage Jenkins | Manage Credentials` global option page.

If it not visible inside a Jenkins job.

You need to enter at least one named private key, in order for a job to display the option:

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/65143385/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-26%20at%2012.26.13.png?version=1&modificationDate=1351250826000&api=v2]

Comment: Hi VonC. Thanks for the answer. I don't see "Manage Credentials" under "Manage Jenkins". I see only "Configure Global Security" and "Configure Credentials". I have "Credentials Plugin" installed and based on plugin's description I should have “Manage Credentials” screen on the “Manage Jenkins". Do you know I need to configure anything else to see "Manage Credentials" option?

Comment: @pmajcher Right, I see it in my Jenkins1, not Jenkins2

Comment: what do you mean by Jenkins1 and Jenkins2? Do you have two instances of Jenkins and you see "Manage Credentials" in one of them only?

Comment: @pmajcher No, I mean I have an instance of a Jenkins 1.6xx, and another server with an instance of Jenkins 2.1xx.

Comment: thanks, Have you configured SSH Agent Plugin on Jenkins 2?

Comment: @pmajcher No, I haven't: I'll check this next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

I also din't see the "Manage Credentials" Options. I'm still tinkering.. see below

My current location

Jenkins >  credentials > system > global credentials

 its not very obvious how to get here.. so, here are some hacks/ work arounds. 

 global credentials link isn't very obvious.. see screen shot or type in browser the path below 
YOURIP:YOURPORT/credentials/store/system/domain/_/

Once at location: you should see Add Credentials in sidebar menu or href text link "adding some credentials?"

I see 1 SSH option here. "SSH with username and Private Key"

[image]
will update results.