# Exception while adding ssh credentials to Jenkins programmatically

Tags: jenkins, curl, ssh, ssh-keys

I have used a method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616660/how-to-create-jenkins-credentials-via-the-rest-api) to add credential to Jenkins programmatically. It worked successfully for adding secret texts and secrets files. But it gives an exception while adding ssh private keys. Below is the curl command I used.

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/jenkins/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' \
--data-urlencode 'json={
"": "0",
"credentials": {
"scope": "GLOBAL",
"id": "temp",
"username": "temp",
"privateKeySource": {
  "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$FileOnMasterPrivateKeySource",
  "privateKeyFile": "/home/udhan/private-key.pem",
},
"stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
}
}'
```

Here is the exception I get.

```
A problem occurred while processing the request.
Please check <a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/issue-tracker">our bug tracker</a> to see if a similar problem has already been reported.
If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem.
If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue.
When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins.
<a href="https://jenkins.io/redirect/users-mailing-list">The users list</a> might be also useful in understanding what has happened.</p><h2>Stack trace</h2><pre style="margin:2em; clear:both">org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$FileOnMasterPrivateKeySource
at org.kohsuke.stapler.ClassDescriptor.loadConstructorParamNames(ClassDescriptor.java:265)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:765)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:83)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:678)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just bumped into this same problem right now.  Rather than using a pem file, I ended up putting the SSH pem's value into a variable and passed it that way instead.

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'https://{{jenkins_admin_username}}:{{jenkins_admin_password}}@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
SSH_KEY="$(cat /your/ssh/pem)"
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST 'https://{{jenkins_admin_username}}:{{jenkins_admin_password}}@localhost:8080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials' --data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "'test-jenkins-id'",
    "username": "'test-username'",
    "password": "",
    "privateKeySource": {
      "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
      "privateKey": "$SSH_KEY",
    },
    "description": "test-jenkins-ssh description",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
  }
}'
```

Not that I went with https instead of http here as we're passing things that should be secured.

I hope this helps.