# Create User, Job and Pipeline in Jenking using Cli or REST API in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and wants to create a user who can subsequently create Job and pipelines.

I also wants this job/pipeline to be triggered as per schedule which should also be created using CLI or RESTFul APIs.

I tried this URL

[Creating user in Jenkins via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716242/creating-user-in-jenkins-via-api/33488587)

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

To create a user you can simply go to **Manage Jenkins** and then **Manage Users**.

You have access to **Create User** on this page.

I recommend you to add the ***Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin*** to your Jenkins server.

You can find more information at this link:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/#authorization

> Edit:

If you want to do it programmatically, you can do it with the [Script Console](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/) of JENKINS.

When your script is ready, you can even launch the script remotely via a web-request.

[example of script  from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716242/creating-user-in-jenkins-via-api)

[example from jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Grant+Cancel+Permission+for+user+and+group+that+have+Build+permission)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to achieve all programatically either Groovy or Java code. Can it be possible?