# Unable to run Jenkins after El Capitan Update

Tags: macos, jenkins

I've been tasked with upgrading a mac box to El Capitan for reasons. El Capitan is up and running along with the most recent version of XCode.

I followed these steps to deal with the new SIP:

[How To Install Homebrew in Mac OS X El Capitan](http://digitizor.com/install-homebrew-osx-el-capitan/)

[How to fix permission issues on Homebrew in OS X El Capitan?](http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/)

I got all of those things back in order (or at least seemingly so), but the Jenkins for the box seems to be down due to being unable to access the config.xml file. Thinking it was more permission issues (as this is why I did the steps in the two cited links), I found this post [Reset Jenkins Configuration Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/reset-jenkins-configuration-command-line) and I confirmed the steps on the [Jenkins Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) and I performed the required steps:

```
1)Stop Jenkins (the easiest way to do this is to kill the servlet container.)
2)Go to $JENKINS_HOME in the file system and find config.xml file.
3)Open this file in the editor.
4)Look for the <useSecurity>true</useSecurity> element in this file.
5)Replace true with false
6)Remove the elements authorizationStrategy and securityRealm
7)Start Jenkins
```

But when I go to Jenkins I still get the Unable to access `/.../config.xml`

As I said, I'm new to this whole process (and in fact dealing with a mac), so does anyone more experienced than I have an idea of what is going on?

Here is the stacktrace for reference:

```
org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/config.xml
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:246)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:43)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:899)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:801)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:214)
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Unable to read /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:170)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:2527)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:146)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:259)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:888)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:187)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: -1 : -1
---- Debugging information ----
message             : -1
cause-exception     : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
cause-message       : -1
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/disabledAdministrativeMonitors
line number         : 3
version             : null
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1061)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1045)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:166)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.entrySet(OrderRetainingMap.java:77)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:511)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.OrderRetainingMap.<init>(OrderRetainingMap.java:36)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.buildMap(FieldDictionary.java:135)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.FieldDictionary.fieldOrNull(FieldDictionary.java:113)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.getFieldOrNull(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:186)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.fieldDefinedInClass(RobustReflectionConverter.java:328)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:269)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:222)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 18 more
```

I also tried the solution from this Jira: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9774 Still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a java versioning issue. After the El Capitan update it prompted me to re-install Java and the default install was of course Java 8. Rolled back to Java 7 and installed Maven 3.0.2 and everything is up and running.