# Jenkins login issue

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Just setup jenkins on Ubuntu v16 laptop.

I have followed the installation steps from this [page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)

After I setup, I fetched the setup password from `/var/logs/jenkins/jenkins.log` & was able to setup the admin user/password. I made a note of the creds.

I was also able to access & setup a simple `helloworld pipeline job`.

I stepped out and came back to my desk after about 20mins. The session has logged me out & I am not able to log-in with the creds. I have tried removing jenkins & setting it back. It still seems to retain the creds somewhere & now I am getting to the login page with bad credentials error everytime.

```
Invalid login information. Please try again. 
Try again
If you are a system administrator and suspect this to be a configuration problem, see the server console output for more details.
```

Need help figuring out what is happening. My logs have no useful information related to this error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.se].

Comment: There are questions related to setup issues with `Java` & `Groovy`, and `Jenkins` issue is as good as the above. I would like to differ from your opinion & request you to take back your vote to close.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to withdraw a close vote. My vote won't matter unless several other users agree with it. (BTW, Java and Groovy are both programming languages.)

Comment: @ sudhishkr: by any chance did you configured security related plugins (LDAP, Active directory?)

Comment: Just in case you have noted it already : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/reset-jenkins-configuration-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/reset-jenkins-configuration-command-line), the quickest way to get around this would be to disable security altogether by making the following change to your Jenkins `config.xml` file:

```
<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

After rebooting your Jenkins instance, you should be able to return to the admin page and set everything up from there.

An alternate solution to this is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564821/5012320), which should accomplish what you want whereby preserving the security of your Jenkins instance (thus making this a more ideal solution). You would instead update the `passwordHash` section of your Jenkins `config.xml` file:

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$razd3L1aXndFfBNHO95aj.IVrFydsxkcQCcLmujmFQzll3hcUrY7S</passwordHash>
```

The `passwordHash` section of the `config.xml` file is a child tag under `<hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm_-Details>`.

You would again need to reboot Jenkins once this change has been made, and you would login using the password 'test'. Of course, you could provide your own hash of a different password which would be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the initial password can be found in the below location:-

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword
```

try this method

Comment: The user clearly stated this was for Ubuntu...