# unable to login to jenkins.Throwing an error like invalid login information,please try again.Even we entered correct credential

Tags: jenkins

Unable to login to jenkins even if we enter valid credential

[image: login-jenkins-failed]

Comment: Check the log file. Pretty hard to help you with this amount of information.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the password by manually editing the configuration file for your user. (/jenkins/users/username/config.xml) and update the contents of passwordHash:

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$razd3L1aXndFfBNHO95aj.IVrFydsxkcQCcLmujmFQzll3hcUrY7S</passwordHash>
```

Restart Jenkins and login using below password:

```
test
```

Have a look at below thread: [Reset Jenkins Configuration Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/reset-jenkins-configuration-command-line])

Comment: how to find config.xml in high sierra

Comment: This is the path on my PC: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\config.xml`

Comment: On my windows 10 it's at C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins

Comment: On my windows it was `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\users\<jenkins username>_nummbers\config.xml` (can't they stop changing the default folders for config files?)

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have provided, i think you were pressing wrong credentials. However, i know of 2 options to fix this : 
1) Go to your Jenkins installation Directory (Usually `C:\Users\<UserID>\.jenkins\`), look for `config.xml` - Check for below xml tags
`useSecurity` `authorizationStrategy`. You can play around with the values to get anonymous access/allow signup etc..
2) Re-install the jenkins itself - Remember to backup your jobs/workspace if you have already coded some jobs.

Comment: Hey Sudheer,
thanks MAN.It worked after reinstalling.

Comment: can't find this path in high sierra

Comment: This path here for me: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

In case , you are installing as Jenkins as a 'Windows service' , then you can use username: admin & initial password: 'provided while installing Jenkins' to log in.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673792/2076973), I had to do restart the Jenkins service for the change to take effect:

Go to the config folder (seems to be in one of the following for different versions):

```bash
# Windows (my machine)
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\users\<jenkins username>_<random numbers>\config.xml 

# Windows (Other)
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\config.xml

# Linux 
/jenkins/users/username/config.xml

# (Others?...)
```

Change contents of `passwordHash` tag for this:

```
<passwordHash>#jbcrypt:$2a$10$razd3L1aXndFfBNHO95aj.IVrFydsxkcQCcLmujmFQzll3hcUrY7S</passwordHash>
```

Restart Jenkins service:

```bash
# Windows
# (Inside Jenkins folder: C:\Program Files\Jenkins)
jenkins.exe restart

# Linux
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Login using your username and the password:

```
test
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycase after commenting or removing the below line, it worked!

1. Goto:
   C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\config.xml
2. Remove the below line in config.xml:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgzIl.png)

Answer (score 0):

While solving same issue, I noticed there were two folders .Jenkins in my system.
That's why attempts to change config.xml failed for me.
For version 2.401.2 it was `ProgramData\Jenkins\.Jenkins` (not that one in {your_user} folder).
Hope this saves somebody's time

Answer (score 0):

for me changing the port worked!

i used port 8090 instead of 8080
`docker run -p *8090:8080* -p 50000:50000 --restart=on-failure -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17`