# How to reset Jenkins Admin account password? I am running Jenkins in Docker in windows

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have created an Admin account in Jenkins after unlocking the Jenkins and doing the initial setup.
Now I have forgot the password of the admin account and I am not able to login Jenkins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset Jenkins security settings from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/how-to-reset-jenkins-security-settings-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, enter the docker container by using

```
sudo docker exec -it [containerID] bin/bash
```

Your container is likely clean and need to install editing tools (or just use vim if you like!), run

```
apt-get update && apt-get install nano
```

Then, find the `config.xml` file. For my container, it is in `/var/jenkins_home/config.xml`. You can also try `/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`.

```
nano /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
```

[image: Terminal Screen Cap]
Change the `useSecurity` tag to false.

```
docker restart [ContainerID]
```

Now, you can visit the Jenkins page and it should be showing the Dashboard right the way without password. You should reset the password, by going to `Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Configure Global Security`
, set `Security Realms` to `Jenkins' own user database` and press `Apply`.

Next, go to `People` and click the admin account, you should be redirected and see a button named `Configure`, set a new set of password in `Password` section and press `Apply`.

Then, go to `Configure Global Security` again, set `Authentication` to the option **other than** `Anyone can do anything`

Your password should have been reset, finally, go set the value of `useSecurity` to true again and restart the container. Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

As you running Jenkins in a Docker container you have to go to the inside of the container.

by typing below command $docker exec -it (container-ID) /bin/bash

After entering the container you should follow these step which mentioned on this post https://techpostal.blogspot.com/2020/01/how-to-reset-jenkins-admin-password.html

then check it and one more thing when you are done with the resetting password you shoud commit the docker images for future use of that image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker, all of that described before seems to me too much of a hazzle.

1. Remove container and volumes used
2. Start afresh again

Reference: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/

Comment: I think this is not a good approach as you want to keep the settings configured in Jenkins, killing and start another Jenkins container is not helping.

Comment: The OP stated he is starting to use jenkins on a docker container, as I understand is a new fresh instance, so nothing to keep, or did I miss something?