# Unable to reset Jenkins password in latest version 2.361.4

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to reset Jenkins password, and I know a few approaches mentioned on: [How to reset Jenkins security settings from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988849/how-to-reset-jenkins-security-settings-from-the-command-line)

Above mentioned approaches are not working in Jenkins's latest version; I guess they have disabled them in the new version.

Is there any workaround to reset Jenkins's password in its new version?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config.xml in the /var/lib/jenkins directory. In that means:

```
<useSecurity>False</useSecurity>
```

then restart jenkins.